# which database provide easy Encryption of data? realm vs greenDao vs (room+saferoom) vs (sqlLite+cipher)

Tags: android, database, realm, android-room, greendao

currently, in our Project, we are using sqlLite+cipher old school method for storing in database and encryption. we planning to rewrite need advice on what to use for database+encryption 
our app is of 12MB out of which 7Mb is only for cipher Files.
what should I go for greenDao or realm or room+safeRoom or continue with existing code? your input would be really valuable 
I was planning for greenDao or realm since they provide encryption out of the box. not very convinced with safeRoom.

Thanks in advance

Comment: got to know about "requery". oh man i am confused now :D